# Drupal module regarding block/timezone

Tags: drupal

What are the steps I can take to do this task

Write a short module that performs as many of the following tasks as you can.

1. Display a block that shows the time the user last logged in. “You last logged in at “
2. In the user’s current time-zone
3. Have the block automatically be placed in left side-rail region (if available)
4. Make sure that the block is not visible for non-logged in users.
5. Allow the message to be configured per user.
6. Frontend Javascript should collapse (animated) the block after 10 seconds.
7. Make this a panels ctools content type (pane) in addition to a standard block

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment that outlines the 7 steps you should follow to achieve the task. Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I din't get how to add number 6 and how to configure the block